# Disable mouse wheel scroll for DevExpress XtraScrollableControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I dont want my XtraScrollableControl to scroll using mouse wheel. But scroll should be enabled and visible and I should scroll XtraScrollableControl
using mouse drag.
If i set

```
xtraScrollableControl1.AutoScroll = false;
```

the scroll bars are not visible anymore and if I set

```
xtraScrollableControl1.FireScrollEventOnMouseWheel = true
```

then nothing happens.I am using DevExpress 13.2.5

Comment: Instead of just giving a minus vote please let me know my mistake

Answer (score 0):

It looks like DevExpress may have a solution for this in their KB:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18512

Take a look and see if that meets your needs.  I was going to try to replicate the problem and the suggested fix, but I can't figure out what a "Scrollable Control" is.  Can you point me to that specific control?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way is to create `XtraScrollableControl` descendant and override its `OnMouseWheelCore` method with no code on it.
Here is example:

```
public class NoMouseWheelControl : XtraScrollableControl
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheelCore(MouseEventArgs ev)
    {
        //No more wheel.
    }
}
```